# Why can't this character in Game of Thrones have children?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

Can Daenerys Targaryen have children?

I don't remember this being brought up in the show, before, but recently I got the impression that she won't have children and I'm wondering whether she can and is choosing to show no interest, or whether she just can't for some reason. If so, why not?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't even read the question yet since I read already in the beginning it is about the episode 6 of the current season. I just want to ask if it is ok to ask about a episode that has been illegally leaked.

Comment: @LeonX There was nothing illegal about the leak, it was accidentally broadcast by HBO Spain

Comment: @LeonX Also, the question is not a spoiler, since it was brought up early in book 1. It's something the show decided to skip over, and never bring up, until now, that the books have brought up many times early on.

Comment: Still a leak not intended by HBO. People were arrested for the first leak.

Comment: @LeonX I didn't say they intended it, I only corrected your mention of "illegally".

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/60203

Comment: Relevant on SFF: [Can Daenerys conceive a Child?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/60198/54887)

Comment: @Aegon  Maarten already mentioned it in comment and it's irrelevant from show perspective as they skipped the womb part in the show.

Comment: @LeonX refer respective meta :[Questions regarding obviously pirated movies](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1380/questions-regarding-obviously-pirated-movies)

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yes I have noticed that. Given that it is just a link, It might not be appear to be related to people giving a cursory glance. I have added the mark up to add link description, which I believe makes people more likely to click links. And IIRC this has happened more or less the same way in the show

Comment: @Aegon it's weird that they skipped womb part of the quote from the show and still say she is incapable of having a child.

Comment: Please take any extended conversation to chat.

Comment: Can someone comment on why this question is so heavily downvoted?

Comment: @PaleBlueDot because few people have very thin skin towards spoilers and original version of question included content from accidentally aired episode.

Comment: @LeonX: `Still a leak not intended by HBO. People were arrested for the first leak.` But no one was arrested for **watching** the leak. If I rob a bank and give some of that money to a beggar, that beggar is not guilty of any crime by spending that money. The arrest happened because of the _nature_ of how the leak was obtained; which is unrelated to having watched it. If this question was about **how to download** the leak, I would agree with you, but not when it discusses the content of the episode itself. Leaked information is inherently in the public domain (that's what a leak is!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the show it's referenced in "The Prince of Winterfell" (*Game of Thrones*, S02E08):

> DAENERYS: (TO JORAH) They *are* my children, and **they are the only children I will ever have.**
>   <sub>—"The Prince of Winterfell" (*Game of Thrones*, S02E08)</sub>

In the books it's spelled out in Mirri Maz Duur's prophecy, which the show borrows from, but admittedly omits the line that is key to this question:

> "When the sun rises in the west and sets in the east," said Mirri Maz Duur. "When the seas go dry and mountains blow in the wind like leaves. When your womb quickens again, and you bear a living child. Then he will return, and not before."

In book five, *A Dance With Dragons*, Daenerys actually explicitly shows that she herself believes she can't have children:

> There would be no son for Loraq, no heir to unite dragon and harpy. *When the sun rises in the west and sets in the east, when the seas go dry and mountains blow in the wind like leaves.* Only then would her womb quicken once again...
>   <sub>—Daenerys IV, A Dance with Dragons: A Song of Ice and Fire: Book Five</sub>

There is no specific, explicitly stated reason she can't have children (it's, in fact, possible that she may be able to bear children, but that she strongly believes Maz's prophecy due to trauma), but the witch's prophecy implies she is barren, which can be due to multiple reasons. Dany, having witnessed what her blood magic did to her son and Khal, has good reason to strongly suspect the magic also affected her ability to have children.

Answer (score 3):

**Daenerys was cursed by Mirri Maz Duur.**

> "When the sun rises in the west and sets in the east," said Mirri Maz Duur. "When the seas go dry and mountains blow in the wind like leaves. When your womb quickens again, and you bear a living child. Then he will return, and not before."

Daenerys sacrificed her only child (fathered by Khal Drogo) to save Drogo's life.

Comment: That's not a curse...it's a prophecy.

Comment: That quote is from the books, though, right? It wasn't really brought up in the show. They ommitted that line about "**when your womb quickens again**". The *only* reference I could find is: `Dany says to Jorah "They're the only children I'll ever have" (speaking of dragons)`